# Is it possible to use CDI interceptor to intercept method invocation from an Entity?

Tags: jpa, cdi

Team lead wants to writing some business methods inside of Entity class, such as following:

```
@Entity
public class SomeProcess extends SomeProcessBase implements Serializable {

    @SomeInterceptor
    public void start() {
        //do some business logics
    }

    @SomeInterceptor
    public void abort() {
        // do some business logics
    }

    ...

}
```

Can we use CDI interceptor mechanism to intercept non-contextual entity objects?

Comment: What exactly is the reason you want to use CDI interceptors instead of straightforwardly [JPA's own interceptors (listeners)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) such as `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate`, and friends? Why don't you just do the CDI job in the business service class associated with the entity?

Comment: Thanks for replying BalusC. We are doing transition (which made the entity, a reactive object, transite from one state to another state) based lifecycle validation and notification.

Comment: For example, once the "SomeProcess" entity object is already in "started" state, then the start method will not be invoked, and an exception event will occur to let the user or backend service know the start request is illegal.  So the Entity's lifecycle interceptors are insufficient.

Comment: Okay. Why is the class a JPA entity instead of a true business service then?

Comment: According to Core J2EE Patterns, there are Application Service Pattern and Business Object(Entity or Composite Entity) Pattern. And the Application Service Pattern is to decouple the dependencies between different Business Objects. And business object can be implemented as entity object itself or the business service. We prefer much encapsulation so we choose business object, and we thought business service breaks some encapsulation with entity property access. Business service is useful to perform logics within the business domain and whose scope is beyond the entity object lifecycle itself.

Comment: Patterns are patterns not detailed maps, use some common sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO.

And the next direction for this is moving to BCEL.

After a few days study, i finally finished with BCEL to achieve method intercepting.

Rough Solution:
 1. Using java instrument framework to transform byte code at class load time. [Click Reference](http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/). 
 2. Transform byte code with a [bytecode manipulation](http://uwyn.com/download/bytecode_real_world.pdf) lib, such as ASM, Javassist, or BCEL. While transforming bytecode, manually writing target java file, and using some tool class provided by those libs to generate java code which can create byte codes from the target class file, after some encapsulation and boxing-and-unboxing and etc, then transform byte code part would be ready. BCEL provides BCELifier class to generate those java code, and the [bytecode manipulation](http://uwyn.com/download/bytecode_real_world.pdf) also mentioned some other tools for the other libs.
 3. Try [Lifecycle](https://github.com/zhongdj/Swordfish/tree/master/Platform/Lifecycle) open source project on github.com, which provides Java based Lifecycle description language, it's kind of using Java to describe UML state machine with meta-driven style. And for method intercepting, please refer to [BCELClassFileTransformer.java](https://github.com/zhongdj/Swordfish/blob/master/Platform/Lifecycle/src/main/java/net/madz/bcel/BCELClassFileTransformer.java)
 4. Contact me for more help.

Comment: You could have included a few more details :/